# Is DNC/DNR stronger than "prompt" non-computability?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

We propose a (probably not new) definition. Let $\varphi_e$ be an effective enumeration of the partial computable functions.

A total function $f$ is promptly non-computable (PNC) [or promptly non-recursive, PNR] if there exists a computable function $h$ such that, for all $\varphi_e$, there is some $m\le h(e)$ with $\varphi_e(m)\ne f(m)$. (Possibly because $\varphi_e(m)$ diverges.) In other words, $f$ differs from $\varphi_e$ by position $h(e)$.

This is a weakening of diagonal non-computability (DNC) [or diagonally non-recursive, DNR], where we say $f$ is DNC if, for all $\varphi_e$, $\varphi_e(e)\ne f(e)$. Naturally, DNC would be a special case of PNC, taking $h$ to be the identity.

Does every PNC function compute a DNC function? Or is DNC actually stronger than PNC?

Comment: Could you clarify: you insist that $f$ is a total function?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, for the same reason we do so for standard DNC functions; if we allow partial functions to be DNC, there's a trivial computable example. (Specifically, U(e) + 1).

Comment: Well, that function wouldn't have $U(e)\neq f(e)$ in the case $U(e)\uparrow$, since both sides would diverge equally, so I don't take it as a "counterexample". I think the concept makes fine sense when $f$ is partial, provided that you really have $\varphi_e(m)\neq f(m)$, either because one side diverges and the other doesn't, or both converge, but to different values. But it is also fine to require that $f$ is total.

Comment: Ah. Good point, and that's part of why we restrict to total functions... to avoid the debate of whether if $U(e)\uparrow$ and $f(e)\uparrow$, we can say that $U(e)=f(e)$. Thanks for making me clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The graph of the course-of-values variant
$$\{(x,(f(0),\dots,f(x))): x\in \mathbb N\}$$
of such a function would be [effectively immune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_set). Namely, if we enumerate a subset of this graph then there is an associated partial recursive function. Therefore it is equivalent to DNR.

Comment: I see - thanks! I do wonder if there's a nice direct construction, though, taking us from "PNC" to DNR.

Comment: @EricAstor I guess if you trace through the proof that effectively immune computes DNR, the DNR function $g$ ends up being something like $g(x)=\langle f(0),\dots,f(h(x))\rangle$ for a certain $h$. So maybe one can get that a computably bounded $\mathsf{PNC}$ function computes a computably bounded $\mathsf{DNC}$ function, and study the computable growth rates.

Comment: Huh. I can't seem to get my hands on a copy of that proof, actually... and I'm not sure I've seen it cited before. Can you suggest a text or paper?

Comment: If memory serves it is in Jockusch's 1989 paper on DNR functions.